# Display image on hover, centered in the background

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I went through a number of questions regarding displaying image on hover here on Stackoverflow, but couldn't find a solution for my problem.

Right now I managed to display an image in the background of the paragraph once I hover on it. [See on JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/4tubcy8e/)

Ideally what would I like to do achieve: once I hover over an Example1 inside of a paragraph I would like to display Image1 in the background, not below the paragraph, but centered in the background, below all of the elements. [As pictured here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AvDR.jpg).

Hovering on Example2 would ideally display Image2, and Example3 would display Image3.

**HTML**

```
<div id="imgbg">
<p>Portfolio:</p>    
<p>I worked with:<br />
Example1, Example2, Example3, Example4, Example5
</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#imgbg {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

#imgbg:hover {
background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/9bbjE1Mb.jpg');
}
```

Does anyone have a solution? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript as that

```js
    function showBg() {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://i.imgur.com/9bbjE1Mb.jpg')";
    }

    function hideBg() {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = null;

    }
```

```html
<div onmouseover="showBg()" onmouseleave="hideBg()" id="imgbg">
  <p>I worked with:
    <br />Example1, Example2, Example3, Example4, Example5
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should wrap Example1 and Example2 with span tag or div 
and add css rules for these wraps.

```
<span id="ex1">Example1</span>, <span id="ex2">Example2</span>, Example3, Example4, Example5
```

and add css

```
#ex1, #ex2 {
   display:inline-block;
   height:50px;
}

#ex1:hover {
  background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/9bbjE1Mb.jpg');
}

#ex2:hover {
   background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/9bbjE1Mb.jpg');
}
```

Look at https://jsfiddle.net/4tubcy8e/6/

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. This works fine and it solved the first part of my problem. What would be the solution, if I would like to display the image on hover not below the Example1, Example2 and so on? But instead, centered on the website. As pictured here: http://i.imgur.com/QaCWBh3.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may help you.

```css
#imgbg {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 265px;
}

#imgbg .Example:hover:after {
  display: block;
}

#imgbg .Example:after {
  content: '';
  display: none;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/9bbjE1Mb.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -80px;
  margin-left: 145px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="imgbg">
  <p>Portfolio:</p>    
  <p>I worked with:<br />
   <span class="Example">Example1</span>,
   <span class="Example">Example2</span>,
   <span class="Example">Example3</span>,
   <span class="Example">Example4</span>,
   <span class="Example">Example5</span>
  </p>
</div>
```