# Mouse over text to display image in another div (not child) with CSS

Tags: css, hover, visibility, mouseover, display

I'm trying to make something like [this website](http://geordiewood.com/) where you hover over text shows image in the background.
I've tried everything I've found here but nothing's worked. The closest thing I got it to work was from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35450273/9958796) but the image would show inside a small column   minimized where the text is located. I'm open to implementing JS if it's impossible with pure CSS. The code is below but here's my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n6wrcjoh/19/). Help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
            <div class="menu">
                <div class="column">
                    <ul>
                        <li><span>column 1</span></li>
                        <li>filler 1</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <ul>
                        <li><span>column 2</span></li>
                        <li>filler 2</li>
                        <li><a id="preview1" href="#page1">link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a id="preview2" href="#page2">link 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="preview">
                <img id="preview1-show" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x500">
                <img id="preview2-show" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x500">
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 6em;
    position: fixed;
}

.menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
}
.column ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.column li {
    position: relative; 
    display: block;
    padding: .3em;
}
.column li span {
    font-weight: bolder;
}
.column li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.preview {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    visibility: hidden;
}
#preview1:hover ~ #preview1-show {
  visibility: visible;
}
#preview2:hover ~ #preview2-show {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create on text hover

```
{ 
    background-image: url("image url");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: your position;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but my issue is that the image would show inside the div where the linked text is, not like the whole image showing in the background in the example I provided.

Comment: @Dani have you tried absolute positioning when :hover?

Answer (score 0):

nvm I figured it out.
For anyone interested I removed the css that targeted div id's and `visibility:hidden;` from .preview and instead added `display: none; z-index: -1;` to .preview and used this JS code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#preview1').hover(function(){
        $('#preview1-show').show();
    },function(){
        $('#preview1-show').hide();
    });
    $('#preview2').hover(function(){
        $('#preview2-show').show();
    },function(){
        $('#preview2-show').hide();
    });
});
```

This isn't the perfect solution since I have to target each individual link (I have 13) but it works exactly the way I want.
If anyone has more elegant solution please share.